# Selecionar uma div sem ela ter uma class ou um id?

Tags: jquery

Eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte

```
<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>Teste 2</div> <---- Quero selecionar esta
  <div>Teste 3</div>
</div>
```

Como é que eu conseguiria selecionar aquela `div`?

Baseada na solução do @Guilherme Nascimento, eu usei o método dele neste [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uruzeds/10/) mas não consegui o que pretendia.

Para elém disso, existe forma de eu selecionar ainda mais `fundo`?

```
<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>
     <img src="esta_nao.jpg" />
     <img src="teste_teste.jpg" /> <---- Quero selecionar esta
  </div>
  <div>Teste 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você usou `div::nth-child(3)`, mas é apenas um `:`, então deveria ser `div:nth-child(3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o seletor `:nth-child()`, assim:

```js
var elemento = $("#teste div:nth-child(2)");

console.log(elemento.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>Teste 2</div> <!-- Quero selecionar esta -->
  <div>Teste 3</div>
</div>
```

O `nth-child` é usado em CSS também, ou seja não é um seletor exclusivo jQuery e por isto estará disponivel para que usa JavaScript puro, por exemplo:

```js
var elemento = document.querySelector("#teste div:nth-child(2)");

console.log(elemento.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>Teste 2</div> <!-- Quero selecionar esta -->
  <div>Teste 3</div>
</div>
```

O `:nth-child` pode selecionar pela ordem do filho, 1, 2, 3, 4, e assim por diante. Ele também pode selecionar mais de um elemento como elementos apenas impares ou pares, por exemplo:

- `:nth-child(2n+1)` irá selecionar somente os elementos filhos impares
- `:nth-child(2n)` irá selecionar somente os elementos filhos pares

Para ir mais afundo basta ajustar os filhos do seletor, use o seletor `#teste > div > img:nth-child(<posição do filho>)` para isto:

```js
var elemento = $("#teste > div > img:nth-child(2)");

console.log(elemento.attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>
     <img src="esta_nao.jpg" />
     <img src="teste_teste.jpg" /> <!-- Quero selecionar esta -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou então pode pegar por atributo src da imagem:

```js
var elemento = $("#teste > div > img[src='teste_teste.jpg']");

console.log(elemento.attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>
     <img src="esta_nao.jpg" />
     <img src="teste_teste.jpg" /> <!-- Quero selecionar esta -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Se desejar pegar imagens que terminem com `teste_teste.jpg` use `"#teste > div > img[src$=teste_teste.jpg]"`, por exemplo isto seria pego também:

```
<img src="/foo/bar/teste_teste.jpg" />
```

Pois o cifrão `$` vai pegar tudo que termina em `teste_teste.jpg`

> **Nota:** o seletor `>` serve para indicar que o elemento deve ser filho direto do seletor anterior, então aqui `#teste > div > img`:
>
> - `<img>` deverá ser filho direto de `<div>`
> - `<div>` deverá ser filho direto de `<(elemento) id="teste"></(elemento)>` -
>   usei `(elemento)` porque o `#` sem elemento indicado diz que qualquer elemento que contenha o `id` pode ter o filho  `> div` a seguir, é claro que o atributo `id=` **nunca pode ser repetido em HTML**

Comment: Parece que pensamos na mesma solução, hehe!

Comment: Pensei também nesse método mas não tinha arranjado forma de o pôr, vou testar e dou mais informações.

Comment: Resultou! Muito boa explicação.

Comment: Lembrando que para selecionar os impares e pares podemos usar também `:nth-child(odd)` e `:nth-child(even)`

Comment: @JorgeMatheus sim, estes são atalhos, a ideia era explicar o "algoritimo" `an+b` da formula usada, por exemplo, pode selecionar de 3 em 3 ou de 4 em 4

Comment: @I_like_trains show :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, muito bem detalhado. +1

Comment: Editei a questão para mais uma questão :s

Comment: @I_like_trains editei a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Da para fazer dessa forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#teste div:nth-child(2)').css('background-color','red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>Teste 2 selecionada</div> <!--<---- Quero selecionar esta-->
  <div>Teste 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode selecionar pelo texto que ela contém (todo ou parte):

```js
$("#teste div:contains('Teste 2')").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">
  <div>Teste 1</div>
  <div>Teste 2</div>
  <div>Teste 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Método diferente e funcional. +1 :)